# Being sent to a different part of the website

Tags: php, forms, pdo, hyperlink, fetch

I'm working on a register form, for my website.

```
<?php
  include('config.php');

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location:index.php');
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit-registerform'])) {
    Register();
  }

  function Register() {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) &&
       !empty($_POST['password']) &&
       !empty($_POST['lastname']) &&
       !empty($_POST['email'])) {
         // Database Connection:
         require('config.php');
         $MyConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x', $dbusername, $dbpassword);
         $MyConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

         // Information from user:
         $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
         $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
         $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);
         $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

         // Hashing the password:
         $cost = 10;
         $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
         $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
         $hash = crypt($password, $salt);

         // Check if username already exists in the database:
         $findUser = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = :username OR Email = :email");
         $findUser->bindParam(':username', $username);
         $findUser->bindParam(':email', $email);
         $findUser->execute();

         $foundUser = $findUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

         if($username == $foundUser->Username) {
           echo '
             <div id="pop-up">
             This username is already in use. Please choose another one.
             </div>
             ';
         }
         elseif($email == $foundUser->Email) {
           echo '
             <div id="pop-up">
             This email address is already in use. Please sign up with a different one. <br />
             If this is impossible, please <a href="contact.php">contact us</a>.
             </div>
             ';
         }
         else {
           // Store information into the database:
           $sql = $MyConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Lastname, Email) 
             VALUES (:username, :password, :lastname, :email");
           $sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
           $sql->bindParam(':password', $hash);
           $sql->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
           $sql->bindParam(':email', $email);

           if($sql->execute()) {
             echo '
               <div id="pop-up">
               Your account has succesfully been registered. You can start using it right away, by clicking
               <a href="login.php">here</a>.
               </div>
               ';
         }
       }
  }
}
?>
```

When I fill in information in my form, and I already use a username that I have stored into my database, I get the right pop-up, displaying that that username is already in use.
But when I fill in different information (with or without the same email address) I get sent to another webpage, which doesn't exist, so my hosts takes over and displays their error screen.

Does anybody know why it sends the visitor of the webpage to another page (that doesn't exist)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably a missing file, as in `404` maybe? What is the page in question that you're being redirected to, as in "what is being displayed"?

Comment: Have you setup login.php and index.php?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Indeed I get a 404 error.

Comment: @WayneWhitty, I have set login.php and an index.php file.

Comment: Then you need to either check your `file paths` and/or create the other pages if they don't exist. 404 is an indication of just that, "file not found". @JesseDijkstra

Comment: @Fred-ii-, But that's the point, I can't seem to find where it would even send me to another page. Only if I would have a session set, but that's not the case. Since it doesn't immediately send me back to the index.php file.

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside ALL your files and your included files? @JesseDijkstra

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I call that in the config.php. I've added the checking if the Username and/or Email address are already in use later, so before that the form worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$findUser = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT Username FROM Users 
WHERE Username = :username OR Email = :email");
```

You are checking for:

```
$email == $foundUser->Email
```

but you never selected it from the `$findUser` statement.

Comment: That is right. Someone else already pointed this out to me. I should use: $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT Username, Email FROM Users WHERE Username = :username OR Email = :email");

Comment: That's also because I store the output into a new variable ($foundUser)